# Pass a custom object through QWebChanel using Q_PROPERTY

Tags: c++, qt

Can you access custom types using Q_PROPERTY and QWebChannel in javascript?

I've got a class exposed to my javascript app, using QWebChannel, but I can't seem to access it's custom type properties, QString, ints, etc work fine.

For example:

```
class MyData {

public:
  MyData() = default;
  MyData(const QJsonObject &json): a(json["a"].toString()), b["b"].toInt()) {}

  QString a = "hello",
  int b = 4
}
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyData);

class MyService: public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  Q_PROPERTY(MyData myData READ getMyData WRITE setMyData);
}
```

javascript would be something like:

```
//read returns null :(
var myData = window.MyService.myData;
//write setter called, but with default values instead of these
window.MyService.myData = { a = "some string", b = 232 }
```

in javascript reading the value return null and writing is just the default values.

is this possible?

Comment: Have you thought about the order you do things? Because you do remember that in C++ everything must be at least declared before it is used.

Comment: You could show how you use it in js

Comment: use QJsonObject.

Comment: Ok I tried using QJsonObject, but no luck.  I updated the example with how javascript is used.

Comment: what I told you is that you forget MyData and use QJsonObject

Comment: I think the question we all have is why you are using some type other than `QJsonObject` for your `MyService::MyData` property? Why define the type `MyData` at all? This looks like an xy problem.

Comment: Because it's a dataobject that get's passed around and used, my C++ classes don't take QJsonObject.  QJsonObject doesn't define what it the object actually is.  It doesn't seem like that strange of a use case.   Shouldn't the setter in QDataObject call the constructor that take the QJsonObject?

Comment: Ok, I guess there's no Object->JSON magic, so I have to set the Q_PROPERTY to QJsonObject and in the READ/WRITE methods do the conversion to my object.